# Writing BytesIO objects to in-memory Zipfile

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Flask-based webapp that I'm trying to do everything in-memory without touching the disk at all.

I have created an in-memory Word doc (using python-docx library) and an in-memory Excel file (using openpyxl). They are both of type BytesIO. I want to return them both with Flask, so I want to zip them up and return the zipfile to the user's browser.

My code is as follows:

```
inMemory = io.BytesIO()
zipfileObj = zipfile.ZipFile(inMemory, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    try:
        print('adding files to zip archive')
        zipfileObj.write(virtualWorkbook)
        zipfileObj.write(virtualWordDoc)
```

When the zipfile tries to write the virtualWorkbook I get the following error:
**{TypeError}stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not BytesIO**

I have skimmed the entirety of the internet but have come up empty-handed, so if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong that would be amazing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946732/2834978

Comment: `ZipFile` accepts a file-like object; `ZipFile.write` wants the actual bytes: the contents of the virtual document, not the virtual document itself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's easier to mount tmpfs/ramdisk/smth to a specific directory [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351048/how-can-i-create-a-ramdisk-in-python), and just use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` as usual.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the *writestr* method. It accepts both string and bytes.

```
zipfileObj.write(zipfile.ZipInfo('folder/name.docx'),
                                  virtualWorkbook.read())
```