# How to convert base64-format audio files into .wav files without storage them on current directory in Python?

Tags: python, base64, wav, fastapi

I would like to know if there is a better way to convert base64-format audio files into .wav files without storage them on current directory.

The thing is that I get base64-format audio files from user uploading whith a POST request with FastAPI, then I decode them and convert them into .wav files because I need to pass the files over some functions that I created in order to preprocess and transcript the files and those functions use the wave module for .wav files. Due to I created .wav files for nothing more than transcripting them, so I don't need to store them and I finally delete them with os.unlink function.

```
import fastapi_server.preprocessing_f as pr

app = FastAPI()

class AudioBase64(BaseModel):
    audio_name: str = Field(..., min_length=1, example="my-audio")
    data_base64: str = Field(..., min_length=1)

@app.post(
    path="/upload-base64-audios/",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK
)
async def upload_base64_audios(audios: list[AudioBase64] = Body(...)):

    model: str = "~/models"
    dir_name = os.path.expanduser(model)
    output_graph, scorer = pr.resolve_models(dir_name)
    model_retval: List[str] = pr.load_model(output_graph, scorer)

    all_names: list[str] = []
    all_datas: list[str] = []
    all_decode: list[str] = []
    aggresive = 1
    transcriptions: list[str] = []
    new_data: list[str] = []
    final_data: list[str] = []
    header: list[str] = ["audio_name", "transcriptions"]

    for i in range(len(audios)):
        name = audios[i].audio_name
        data = audios[i].data_base64
        decode = base64.b64decode(data)
        all_names.append(name)
        all_datas.append(data)
        all_decode.append(decode)

        filename = "%s.wav" % name
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(decode)

        cwd = os.getcwd()
        files = glob.glob(cwd + "/" + name + ".wav")

        segments, sample_rate, audio_length = pr.vad_segment_generator(
            files[0], aggresive
        )
        for k, segment in enumerate(segments):
            audio = np.frombuffer(segment, dtype=np.int16)
            output = pr.stt(model_retval[0], audio)
            transcript = output[0]
        transcriptions.append(transcript)
        new_data = [all_names[i], transcriptions[i]]
        final_data.append(new_data)

    dir_files = glob.glob(cwd + "/*.wav")
    for file in dir_files:
        os.unlink(file)

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(final_data, columns=header)
    stream = io.StringIO()
    new_df.to_csv(stream, index=False)
    response: Response = StreamingResponse(
        iter([stream.getvalue()]), media_type="text/csv"
    )
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=my-file.csv"
    return response
```

Comment: You could store the data in memory in a [`io.Bytesio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instance.

Comment: @martineau, I tried what you suggested me like this: `buffer =io.BytesIO(decode)  
with io.BytesIO() as f:
   f.write(buffer.getvalue())`  and I send buffer.getbuffer() to my function like this: `segments, sample_rate, audio_length = pr.vad_segment_generator(         buffer.getbuffer(), aggresive)`
, but I got the error: `AttributeError: 'memoryview' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @martineau, as I described before I need decoded data turns into a .wav file because then I read this using Python' wave module

Comment: A `io.BytesIO` is like an open file and can be `read()` like one. Your code appears to be expecting a file name, but they don't have one because they are not real files. Perhaps a ramdisk would be more suitable: [How can I create a ramdisk in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351048/how-can-i-create-a-ramdisk-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [suggested by **@martineau**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280669/how-to-convert-base64-format-audio-files-into-wav-files-without-storage-them-on#comment125996528_71280669),
try writing intermediately to an `io.BytesIO`, but after writing, call [`.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to return the steam position to the start, rather than calling `getbuffer()`
(after writing, the stream position will be at the end, ready for more data)

```py
with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    buffer.write(decode)
    buffer.seek(0)  # rewind stream
    ...
    segments, sample_rate, audio_length = pr.vad_segment_generator(
        buffer, aggresive)
```

Comment: I tried this but I got a `with io.BytesIO("wb") as buffer:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

Comment: @nath_ no need to pass `"wb"` to `BytesIO` which is what it's complaining about! the stream is already readable, writable, and seekable, and the argument is just for pre-allocating (which is rarely necessary) https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO

Comment: @nath_ oh, sorry, I was traveling and I see _I put that there_ fixed now

Comment: thanks!, it finally works. Just the function call must be one level inside (indentation thing)